What would be a good humorous alternative to "Let's get a move on"?
You're stuck in traffic. It's bumper-to-bumper for no apparent reason, and you're annoyed. You want to shout:
"Guys, let's get a move on!"
But that's trivial and boring.
What would be a good humorous (unexpected) alternative?
"Guys, let's tear off!"
"Let's zip along, people!"
"Let's just rush!"
"Let's spring off like an arrow!"
"Guys, let's zoom out of here!"
"Guys, let's race ahead!"
"Guys, let's rush through!"
Or? ...
UPD:
"Let's speed off like lightning!"
"Let's ride off like the dickens!"

The less than civilized might use Let's make like a baby and head out!

None of your examples are native expressions, and they aren't idiomatic in the UK at least.  These all sound very strange and aren't funny.  What do people really say when they are frustrated because they are stuck in traffic?  It usually involves a swear word or two. There's absolutely no point shouting at other drivers though, because they are stuck in the traffic jam just like you.

"Move your fat ass/arse" or similar is sometimes used among friends. But if you want something "unexpected" then nothing on this page probably counts.

Pull your finger out

to start working hard, especially after a period of low activity:

The phrase is of WW2 RAF origin and common in the UK. It might be considered slightly rude because what you are pulling your finger out of is unspecified.
